# Hi ! React issues i need assistance with event handlers

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to make a components props(sideBarInfo) details show up on the left column of a Page after clicking on a corresponding component(thumbnail) on the right column of the same Page.

Please note that all imports and exports are used in the main project(i removed them here).
I've also imported all components into the main (Page.js). Yet i keep getting a Type error for the onClick.

This is the first component - *Thumbnail*

```
class Thumbnail extends React.Component {
    render(){
      return (
        <div className="Work" onClick={(e) => this.props.click(this.props.work)} >
            <div className="image-container">
              <img src={this.props.work.imageSrc} alt={this.props.work.imageSrc}/>
            </div>
            <div className="Work-information">
            <p> {this.props.work.work}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
      } }
```

This is the *ThumbnailList*

```
    class ThumbnailList extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state= {
  works: [
      {
      id: 0,
      work: 'Work 1',
      imageSrc: W1,
      view: '#',
      selected: false
    },
      {
      id: 1,
      work: 'Work 2',
      imageSrc: W2,
      view: '#',
      selected: false
        },         
      ]
    }
  }

      handleCardClick = (id,card) => {
        console.log(id);

        let works= [...this.state.works];

        works[id].selected = works[id].selected ? false : true ;

        works.forEach(work=>{
          if(work.id !== id){
            work.selected = false;
          }
        });

        this.setState({
          works
        })
      }

      makeWorks = (works) => {
        return works.map(work => {
          return <Thumbnail work={work} click={(e => this.handleCardClick(work.id,e ))} key={work.id} />
        })
      }


      render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <div className="scrolling-wrapper-flexbox">
              {this.makeWorks(this.state.works)}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
  }
```

This is the *sidebarInfo*

```
function SidebarInfo(props) {
return (
  <img width="370" height="370" src= {props.imageSrc} />
    <p> {props.work} </p>
);}
```

This is the problematic *Page* - the boldened keeps giving a Type error(cannot read property 'selected' of undefined.)

```
class Page extends React.Component {

render() {
  return (
      <span>

      <div className="column left">
      <div className="">
      **{this.props.work.selected && <SidebarInfo imageSrc={this.props.imageSrc} /> }**
      </div>
      </div>

      <div className="column right" >
            <div>
                <ThumbnailList  />
            </div>
         </div>
      </span>
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: "Yet i keep getting a Type error for the onClick." Can you please post the error in full?  In addition, I might recommend [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The error : (cannot read property 'selected' of undefined.) ... I just read up your link, i'd apply the principles. I'm quite new here. Thanks !

Comment: How is `<Page ...>` set?  I mean, clearly, if you get "cannot call 'something' on undefined" on Page.js  when calling `this.props.work.something`, it means that you didn't set the work prop.

Comment: Hi, Akeymann: Can you please put your code you're asking a question about in your question?  Your link might go down in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a check in `this.props.work.selected` like this `this.props.work && this.props.work.selected`

To ensure that `this.props.work` is defined before checking on `this.props.work.selected`

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the help. The error did clear out but the `<sideBarInfo />` component still doesn't appear after the click.                                                                                                             As per defining `this.props.work`, it is defined in the `<ThumbnailList />` component which I Imported into the main `<Page />` component.  I believe that suffices?

Comment: @Akeymann it is hard for me to debug in this view, can you create a working demo in codesandbox with the code and I'll try to help you with it

Comment: thanks, i followed your suggestion. Here's a quick working demo in codesandbox  (https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-sky-y9d3c?file=/src/App.js) . Please note that the `<Page />` component i mentioned earlier is now `App.js`

Comment: Hi ! Pls see https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-sky-y9d3c?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The `App.js` in your code doesn't have props passed into it.

Comment: Hello ??  i havne't heard from you since your offered your help

Comment: Sorry, but your code sample has too many issues to discuss in a Q&A, so that's why I didn't follow up.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer this for anyone interested.

there were some foundational errors in my file arrangement which have been corrected.

After refactoring, i was able to achieve what i wanted using 3 classes/functions in; App.js, Thumbnail.js and SideBarInfo.js

see one working solution with styling on this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-sky-y9d3c

See Solution below;

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      works: [
        {
          id: 0,
          work: "Work 1",
          imageSrc:
            "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584608168573-b6eec7a04fd7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=701&q=80",
          view: "#",
          selected: false
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          work: "Work 2",
          imageSrc:
            "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581665269479-57504728e479?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=701&q=80",
          view: "#",
          selected: false
        }
      ]
    };

    this.handleCardClick = this.handleCardClick.bind(this);
    this.makeWorks = this.makeWorks.bind(this);
    this.showWorks = this.showWorks.bind(this);
  }

  handleCardClick = (id, Thumbnail) => {
    console.log(id);

    let works = [...this.state.works];

    works[id].selected = works[id].selected ? false : true;

    works.forEach((work) => {
      if (work.id !== id) {
        work.selected = false;
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      works
    });

   
  };

  makeWorks = (works) => {
    return works.map((work) => {
      return (
        <Thumbnail
          work={work}
          click={(e) => this.handleCardClick(work.id, e)}
          key={work.id}
        />
      );
    });
  };

  showWorks = (works) => {
    let i = 0;
    var w = [];
    while (i < works.length) {
      if (works[i].selected) {
        w = works[i];
      }
      i++;
    }
  return ( <SidebarInfo imageSrc={w.imageSrc} work={w.work} /> );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <span>
          <div> { this.showWorks(this.state.works)} </div>
  <div className="">
            <div className="scrolling-wrapper-flexbox">
              {this.makeWorks(this.state.works)}
            </div>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Thumbnail extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <div className="column left">
        {/* this.props.work.selected && <SidebarInfo work={this.props.work.work} imageSrc={this.props.work.imageSrc}/> */}
        </div>
        <div className="column right">
      <div className="Work" onClick={(e) => this.props.click(this.props.work)}>
        <div className="image-container">
          <img src={this.props.work.imageSrc} alt={this.props.work.imageSrc} />
        </div>
        <div className="Work-information">
          <p> {this.props.work.work}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
     
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Thumbnail;


function SidebarInfo(props) {
  return (
    <div className="one">
    <div className="Work">
      <h1> NAME </h1>
      <div className="image-container">
        <img
          width="370"
          height="370"
          src={props.imageSrc}
          alt={props.imageSrc}
        />
      </div>
      <p> {props.work} </p>
      <p> {props.view} </p>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SidebarInfo;
```